# Jboss temp VFS grow

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x

I noticed that in my JBoss AS 7.1 installation underJbosHome/domain/servers/serverName i have ~ 900 MB of files in tmp and VFS folder. I just stop my server and delete them manually, than start it again and it's grow again to ~ 900Mb. How is it cleaned up? Should it happen automatically? Is there a tool for it? Can I just remove all those files myself and when ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use following to clean it

-Djboss.vfs.cache=org.jboss.virtual.plugins.cache.IterableTimedVFSCache 
-Djboss.vfs.cache.TimedPolicyCaching.lifetime=1440

Comment: Is this in seconds (1440) ?